# Pig 0.12.0 won't execute shell commands with timezone change using backticks

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, apache-pig, hue

I'm using Hue for PIG scripts on amazon EMR. I want to make a shell call to get the date in a particular timezone into a variable which I will use to define an output folder path for writing the output to. Eventually I want to use a `if else fi` loop to get a particular date from a week, so the time zone will be mentioned at various places in the command.

Sample Script

```
ts = LOAD 's3://testbucket1/input/testdata-00000.gz' USING PigStorage('\t');
STORE ts INTO 's3://testbucket1/$OUTPUT_FOLDER' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Pig parameter definition in Hue:

1. This works: OUTPUT FOLDER = `/bin/date +%Y%m%d`
2. This doesn't work: OUTPUT FOLDER = `TZ=America/New_York /bin/date +%Y%m%d`

Both of the commands execute perfectly in the bash shell. But the second command gives the following error:

> 2015-06-23 21:43:42,901 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.PreprocessorContext  - Executing command : TZ=America/Phoenix /bin/date +%Y%m%d
>   2015-06-23 21:43:42,913 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main  - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Error executing shell command: TZ=America/Phoenix /bin/date +%Y%m%d. Command exit with exit code of 126

[From the GNU manual:](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126.

How do I resolve this?

Configuration details:

- AMI version:3.7.0
- Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.4.0
- Applications:Hive 0.13.1, Pig 0.12.0, Impala 1.2.4, Hue
- Underlying shell: bash
- User: hadoop (while using Pig and while using Bash)

If you need any clarifications then please do comment on this question. I will update it as needed.

[EDIT: Under the hood, Pig calculates the value by executing "bash -c exec (command)" and assigning it to the variable, where (command) is whatever we put as a value for the variable in Hue](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.12.0/org/apache/pig/tools/parameters/PreprocessorContext.java#161)

Comment: it might not like the space between `New_York` and `/bin`

Comment: There's a space between date and "+%Y%m%d", so that seems unlikely that Pig doesn't work with spaces in shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

If I do:

```
date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles"' '+%Y%m%d'
20150624
```

e.g.

```
%default date_dir `date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles"' '+%Y%m%d'`;
```

Comment: It gives me an error in the bash shell: date: illegal option -- -

Comment: I ran it through Hue on Pig. It gave an error: [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer  - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. null
Failed to parse: null

Comment: I did that on Ubuntu 12.04, it might be OS dependent

Comment: Maybe. I am running it on RHEL5. I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: You can check what "date --help" provides for you

Comment: It shows the same command as you typed and the command by itself works in my machine. Sorry I should have been clearer. But when I do "bash -c exec <command>" it doesn't work. That is what Hue does under the hood. I have edited the question to link to the code piece in question which executes the command. Maybe that will help clarify what I am talking about. It's the edit at the bottom with the link.

Comment: Did you try to put some quote and escaped quotes and make it work with basch -c? BTW you can replace Hue by Pig in your edit.

Comment: I replaced the edit. Thanks. So I tried three commands in my bash shell: (1)$ date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles"' '+%Y%m%d' (2)$ bash -c exec date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles"' '+%Y%m%d' (3)$bash -c exec `date --date='TZ="America/Los_Angeles"' '+%Y%m%d'` --------- (1) gives me the date, (2) and (3) don't return anything (assigning it to a variable and checking with the -z flag returns null)